# Does 16 always show up in Collatz Conjecture number leading down to 1?

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Just wondering if 16 always shows up in number > 16 manipulation process leading down to 1 through Collatz conjecture? or are there any exceptions?

I happen to see this link with the animation showing the path only through 16.... 
https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematician-terence-tao-and-the-collatz-conjecture-20191211/?fbclid=IwAR1RG-AIGWlyb3Fjtipn1jXzXw1TP5O8QWSoKe86-FhV7JmP4GbSliOBBzg

Comment: Have you done any work on this yourself?  What have you learned?

Comment: It doesn't. Simply start at two.

Comment: https://www.jasondavies.com/collatz-graph/collatz.png

Comment: Thanks. I will remove this question....

Comment: However, does illustrate that it has to Be that one has to earn A Ph.D degree to have worked on Collatz Conjecture to provide some useful insight :-)....

Comment: None of the pow-$2$ numbers will show up when you use the Reduced Collatz function.

Comment: Very Interesting @Natural Number Guy! https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.07312 seems to talk about this correct? Any simulations available to see the Graph?

Comment: Yes. And here: https://oeis.org/wiki/Reduced_Collatz_function

Comment: The graph would just be the odd numbers connected. I did a crapp drawing in paint here: https://snipboard.io/pOAiuJ.jpg

Comment: My guess would be that there's an infinite number of connections going directly to $1$. Like the numbers of the form $(4^n - 1)/3$.

Comment: Of course, we must assume that the Collatz conjecture is true. If so, the below answers show that $16$ is passed whenever the start value is different from $1,2,4,8$.

Comment: Not to be discourteous...Thanks @Natural Number Guy. That really helped.

Comment: Thank @Peter. I guess there is no such "bottleneck" pattern for Reduced Collatz function, particularly considering 21 to 1....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, lets do this backwards;

The only way to get to 1 is to halve 2,

The only way to get to 2 is to halve 4,

The only way to get to 4 is to halve 8,

The only way to get to 8 is to halve 16,

But 16 can be made 2 different ways - either halve 32 or times 5 by 3 and add 1.
From here all the other branches branch of, and so the answer is yes; It will always pass through 16 (unless of course you start on 1,2,4 or 8)

Comment: You can also get to $4$ by multiplying $1$ by $3$ and adding $1$.  That is how the (only known) cycle works

Comment: That is true, but of course you have to start with 1 in that case, and to do that means you already finished

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that obvious ? The only way to go down is by halving.

Comment: Yes. It is obvious...I can remove the question....

Comment: Maybe it's not that obvious, because every sequence has a starting number and if that number happens to be $2, 4$ or $8$, it goes down to $1$ without passing through $16$!

Comment: @samerivertwice:  the question says "number > 16".

Comment: @YvesDaoust good point.

Answer (score -1):

En efecto 16-8-4-2-1 son la raiz Collatz, pero hay que pensar en el arbol de Collatz a lo grande. al respecto, ¿quien ha pensado en Collatz como un arbol y en sus ramificaciones?
Indeed, 16-8-4-2-1 are fixed in the Collatz root, but you have to think about the Collatz tree in a big way. In this regard, who has thought of Collatz as a tree and its ramifications?

Comment: if, of course, the numbers of which you speak 16-8-4-2-1 are always in the iterations of any number other than them that will be entered because all the numbers reach the one.